# Python bitstamp api invalid nonce error

Tags: python, bitcoin, nonce

A python script was running and now it is not.

```
                public_client = bitstamp.client.Public()

                data=backTestBitCoin.getHistoricalPrices();

                trading_client = bitstamp.client.Trading(username='AAA', key='BBB', secret='CCC')
                tick=trading_client.ticker();

                lastBid = float(tick['bid']);
                lastAsk = float(tick['ask']);
                balances = trading_client.account_balance(); #error thrown from this line
```

I am getting the following error:

```
                    return self._post("balance/", return_json=True)
                  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bitstamp/client.py", line 47, in _post
                    return self._request(requests.post, *args, **kwargs)
                  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bitstamp/client.py", line 80, in _request
                    raise BitstampError(error)
                bitstamp.client.BitstampError: Invalid nonce
```

Has anyone ever experienced this? Not that familiar with the library therefore not sure what is causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating a new api key/secret fixed this problem. I believe it was caused by using a mix of the php api and the python api or the iphone Bitstamp app. I will confirm this suspicion, but the overall solution was to unplug it and plug it back in.

---

Abbreviated solution: My issue was coming from using the following php and python libraries,

[php](https://github.com/willmoss/bitstamp-php-api) 
[python](https://github.com/kmadac/bitstamp-python-client)

Both are A+ great and easy to use.

The error is created because of the following discrepancy in their methods of creating the nonce (neither is more "right" in my opinion, just different).

**php**:

```
                // generate a nonce as microtime, with as-string handling to avoid problems with 32bits systems
                $mt = explode(' ', microtime());
                $req['nonce'] = $mt[1] . substr($mt[0], 2, 6);
                $req['key'] = $key;
                $req['signature'] = $this->get_signature($req['nonce']);
```

**python**:

```
                self._nonce = max(int(time.time()), nonce)
```

Where `time.time()` gives you: 1403366728.072785
and `microtime()` gives you: 1403366859731819.

The solution I put in place is to change the python code to:

`self._nonce = max(int(time.time()*1000000), nonce)` and the error is solved.